# How to trigger T4 template from PowerShell script

Tags: visual-studio-2010, powershell, code-generation, t4

In my VS2010 solution I have set of Powershell scripts and T4 templates based on T4Scaffolding NuGet, everything is working fine with scaffolding and related T4's, but in one of my scripts I need to trigger a T4 template located in another project.

Any simple Powershel cmdlet for this? to just run the template with out passing any parameters or values.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like you can just invoke their command line utility, so you could create a script that just takes the location of your .tt file.

```
param([string] $T4Template)

& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\TextTemplating\10.0\TextTransform.exe" $T4Template
```

Save above as ExecTextTransform.ps1 and then call with your paths.
Example:

```
.\ExecTextTransform.ps1 c:\temp\example.tt
```

See [here](http://pramod-pv.blogspot.com/2011/02/executing-t4-template-from-command-line.html) for an example of calling their command line utility.

Answer (score 0):

Into a Powershell script
[TT file] replace full path of tt file
[TextTransformExe path] example C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\TextTransform.exe

```
$TTFile = "[TT file]"
&"[TextTransformExe path]" $TTFile
```