# Adding dynamic filenames to project using Nuget based on the project name

Tags: c#, nuget

I want to create a NuGet package that adds files to a project based on the project name.

So for example, if I have a project named "ProjectABC" and I import this NuGet package, I want it to add the following folder/file structure:

```
/Schemas
/Schemas/ProjectABC.cs
ProjectABC.cs
```

I'd also like to have the namespace within in the .cs files modified to match the project name:

`namespace ProjectABC.Class1`

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. My suggestion would be for you to have a look at [one existing package](https://nuget.org/api/v2/package/Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact/4.0.8876.1) doing that kind of operation. In particular, have a look at the `install.ps1` and the `vs.psm1` powershell scripts included in that package to see how they add files to current project. The "vs" file contains a few utility functions, based on [ENVDTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.dte.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to automate Visual Studio. Another interesting resource can be found [here](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/209522/powershell-script-examples-for-nuget-packages).

For the namespace part, you might have to rely on [T4 templating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [trigger a .cs file generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9217120/how-to-trigger-t4-template-from-powershell-script) from your install script.